# Why doesn't a Javascript return statement work when the return value is on a new line?

Tags: javascript, return

Consider the following JavaScript:

```js
function correct()
{
    return 15;
}

function wrong()
{
    return
          15;
}

console.log("correct() called : "+correct());
console.log("wrong() called : "+wrong());
```

The `correct()` method in the above code snippet returns the correct value which is `15` in this case. The `wrong()` method, however returns `undefined`. Such is not the case with the most other languages.

The following function is however correct and returns the correct value.

```
function wrong()
{
    return(
          15);
}
```

If the syntax is wrong, it should issue some compiler error but it doesn't. Why does this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

Comment: This is one of the reasons that I put parens around my return values.

Comment: The result is 15, not 10 as show.

Comment: Yes edited. it was written by mistake.

Comment: Crockford has the anser. Just watch: www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook#t=30m39

Comment: The syntax is not wrong, it's valid just not expected. You just have an unreachable statement `15` after a return statement in the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 But if the expression was on the next line the semicolon would still be inserted, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton - when you use parens with the return statement where the opening paren is on the same line as the `return`, the JS interpreter knows not to end the `return` statement until it finds the closing paren regardless of line boundaries.  When you don't use parens, it has to either encounter a semicolon or guess based on line boundaries.  IMO, explicitly telling it is generally better/safer than letting it guess.  If you put the opening paren on the next line after the `return`, then it wouldn't work because the interpreter would have already terminated the `return` statement.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, you didn't say opening on the same line. I understand the rules, but thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Technically, semi colons in javascript are optional.  But in reality *it just inserts them for you* at certain newline characters if it thinks they are missing.  But the descisions it makes for you are not always what you actually want.

And a `return` statement followed by a new line tells the JS intepreter that a semi colon should be inserted after that `return`.  Therefore your actual code is this:

```
function wrong()
{
    return;
          15;
}
```

Which is obviously wrong.  So why does this work?

```
function wrong()
{
     return(
           15);
}
```

Well here we start an expression with an open`(`.  JS knows we are in the middle of an expression when it finds the new line and is smart enough to not insert any semi colons in this case.

Comment: No, semi-colons are officially part of the syntax and there's noting in the syntactic productions of the language that would suggest that semi-colons are optional. It's just that the standard defines the behavior if they're omitted. So, it's more like a special case... it's like an add-on to the standard.

Comment: By optional, I mean that the script is parseable without them.  As opposed to many other languages like C or Java that throw errors at compile/evaluation time when semi colons are absent.  I did not mean to encourage the lack of semi colons in javascript.  If fact, just the opposite.

Comment: It's the word "officially" that bothers me. Omission is tolerated, but semi-colons *are* part of the syntax - officially.

Comment: Fair enough, how about "technically" then :)

Comment: How about "in practice"... However, note that semi-colons aren't optional in all situations, only in certain ones.

Answer (score 5):

If there is nothing after the `return` statement on that line then `;` will be inserted there which will result in returning without any values => return value is `undefined`.

See: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/6/automatic-semicolon-insertion/

Answer (score 2):

The command line of the javascript can not be broken by line breaks. But arguments of functions can be broken, not highly recommended (done in your example).