# Passing string value to $resource in Angluarjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following situation trying to accomplish

Using $resource I am calling

```
App.factory("AppRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {  
       return
        checkPerson: $resource('/api/accountAdd/:netName', { name: '@netName' }, { get: { method: 'GET' } })
     }; 
}]);
```

Than from my cotroller I am calling

```
var netName="Tom"
    AppRepository.checkPerson.get(netName, function (data) {
        alert("success");
    })
```

This doesnt work, because I am passing string for netName. Please let me know how can I pass string value to the factory. I have worked previously with id and it works fine but not sure how to do with string value. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `$resource` specification is incorrect. The second parameter is the `paramDefaults` hash. The keys in that must be the names of placeholders in your URL and the values are strings indicating how to fill in the placeholder.

```
App.factory("AppRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {  
    return {
        checkPerson:
            $resource('/api/accountAdd/:netName',
                // key states that it will replace the ":netName" in the URL
                // value string states that the value should come from the object's "netName" property
                { netName: '@netName' },
                { get: { method: 'GET' } })
    }; 
}]);
```

This should allow you to use the service as follows:

```
var netName="Tom"
AppRepository.checkPerson.get({ netName: netName }, function (data) {
    alert("success");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
var netName="Tom"
    AppRepository.checkPerson.get({ netName: value }, function (data) {
        alert("success");
    })
```

Comment: should that be `{ netName: netName }` ?

Comment: $resource('/api/accountAdd/:netName', { **netName**: '@netName' } ...must be fixed also

Comment: roboli, i meant that value is undefined. fwiw, hash keys do not require quotes. `{netName: netName}` is the same as `{'netName': netName}`

Comment: you're right, i just quote keys when a var has the same name, yeah { netName: netName } should be...

Answer (score 0):

```
AppRepository.checkPerson.get({name: netName}, function (data) {
    alert("success");
})
```

Also, your factory definition is bugged, [you cannot start a new line after a `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new) and right before the return value, your factory returns `undefined`. Move your return value in the same line with `return`.

EDIT: squid314's answer above is the right one

Comment: should that be { netName: netName }