# New line after return ignores following html tag in brackets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-rendering

Trying to return html in render function:
Hitting "Enter" and starting a new line before opening bracket makes the code stop working.

See attached. 1st one is working; 2nd one is NOT working.

[working and non-working functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39308.png)

Comment: Instead of adding an image of your code, it is always better to add the code itself. Put it on a new line and make sure everything is indented by at least 4 spaces, and that the code is well formatted. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Also, is there some reason for you to think that having a return on a line by itself will not just return immediately? ReactJs is just a javascript library (so you should also add 'javascript' to your tags) and browsers will often assume if you've entered a new line after a return then you're done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a Javascript return statement work when the return value is on a new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with plain javascript, not specific to react.

Try writing a function with return alone in the line:

```
function abc() {
  return
  1;
}
```

You might instinctively think that `abd()` will return `1` but that is incorrect, instead it will return `undefined`. If you still don't want to place the whole returned value in one line, then you should use parenthesis (as you do in the working code):

```
function abc() {
  return (
  1);
}
```

Then `abd()` will return `1`. This is useful when you need to return a *lot* of code. I can see that is your case :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I re-phrased the key words and searched again. Found out this page in stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new