# Data fetching with React Native + Redux not working

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-native, fetch, redux

I am building my first React Native app and use Redux for the data flow inside my app.

I want to load some data from my [Parse](http://www.parse.com) backend and display it on a `ListView`. My only issues at the moment is that for some reason, the request that I create using `fetch()` for some reason isn't actually fired. I went through the documentation and examples in the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) and also read this really nice [blog post](http://marconijr.com/post/react-native-and-redux/). They essentially do what I am trying to achieve, but I don't know where my implementation differs from their code samples.

Here is what I have setup at the moment (shortened to show only relevant parts):

#### OverviewRootComponent.js

```
class OverviewRootComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch( fetchOrganizations() )
  }
}
```

#### Actions.js

```
export const fetchOrganizations = () => {
  console.log('Actions - fetchOrganizations');
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('Actions - return promise');
    return
      fetch('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Organization', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'xxx',
          'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'xxx',
        }
      })
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log('fetchOrganizations - did receive response: ', response)
        response.text()
      })
      .then( (responseText) => {
        console.log('fetchOrganizations - received response, now dispatch: ', responseText);
        dispatch( receiveOrganizations(responseText) )
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.warn(error)
      })
  }
}
```

When I am calling `dispatch( fetchOrganizations() )` like this, I do see the logs until `Actions - return promise`, but it doesn't seem to actually to fire off the request. I'm not really sure how how I can further debug this or what resources to consult that help me solve this issue.

Comment: What happens if you run fetchOrganizations() manually?

Comment: Hello @nburk , please have a look on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065390/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-functionevaluating-fetchurl?noredirect=1#comment85136212_49065390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that Redux is expecting a Promise rather than a function.. Is that true?

If so, I think your return function may not be working.

You have a new line after your return, and it's possible JavaScript is (helpfully) inserting a semicolon there.

See here: [Why doesn't a Javascript return statement work when the return value is on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new)

Comment: wow... js sneaky as it is inserts semicolons without me knowing... you can't make this stuff up! :D thanks so much for the hint!!!