# Javascript Module Pattern not working as expected

Tags: javascript, validation, design-patterns, module

When I write the following in Webstorm, it does not work. I get "function name expected." Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm using the book "The Principles of Object-Oriented Javascript," page 81 as my guide.

```
var validator = (function ()
{
    //source: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php
    var EMAIL_PATTERN = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

    return
    {
        validateEmail: function(email)
        {
            return EMAIL_PATTERN.test(email);
        }
    };
}());

console.log(validator.validateEmail("whatever@somewhere.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be just an issue with your return statement

```
var validator = (function ()
{
    //source: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php
    var EMAIL_PATTERN = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

    return {
        validateEmail: function(email)
        {
            return EMAIL_PATTERN.test(email);
        }
    };
}());

console.log(validator.validateEmail("whatever@somewhere.com"));
```

is a corrected version.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your answer. Do you think this is due to javascript grammar or webstorm syntax checking?

Comment: It is due to javascript's interpreter. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new) for more details

Comment: Good ole' Javascript. lol. Thank both of you for the links.